# Choose the right analysis method

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence, methodology

will appreciate your pieces of advice on the following topic.
I have data for each Client ID:

- Geographical Zone ID
- Probability of a client being in that Zone
- Distance from that Zone to the closest ATM
- Monthly average residuals

So, for each client I have three zones he/she might be hanging around with corresponding probabilities. And I know the distance from these zones to the nearest ATM. And I know average monthly residuals on his/her bank account. So, I need to check how the residuals depend on that dataset (Zone - Probability - Distance to ATM). The hypothesis is that the closer ATM is to the most visited zone, the bigger are he residuals, but I'd like to see whether the correlation exists in general and if yes what is the nature of that dependency.
How to better perform it? Should I "pack" that data set (Probability 1 - Distance to ATM 1, Probability 2 - Distance to ATM 2, Probability 3 - Distance to ATM 3) into one figure (e.g. p1*s1 + p2*s2 + p3*s3) and then check correlation, then regression? Or do you probably know standard approaches?

Big thanks.